# Why $fetch does not cache data in Nuxt3?

Tags: nuxtjs3

Nuxt3 has 3 ways of fetching data: `useFetch`, `useAsyncData` and `$fetch`. The data is cached for the first two, but not for the last. Why?

**The use case:**

There is a page with tests (only names). So I use `useFetch` to get the tests. It works perfectly well. Then when a user clicks on a test I would like to display a popup with questions related to the test and other details. I feel like the proper way to do it is to use `$fetch`, but it does cache data, which I think would be a good thing to do, because this data does not change often. Using `useFetch` does not feel right, because such features as accessing `pending` does not work in event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your use case, where you want to display a popup with test questions and details when a user clicks on a test, using `$fetch` to make a fresh request for that specific test data seems like the appropriate approach. Since the data is not expected to change often and you want to ensure you're always showing the latest data when the user clicks on a test, caching may not be ideal in this scenario.

Comment: Actually, I do not want to ensure the latest data is shown. Getting the latest data after the refresh is fine. If the same test is clicked twice, I would like to show cached data.

Comment: If you want to show cached data when the same test is clicked twice, you can take advantage of the caching behavior provided by the useFetch or useAsyncData functions. When using either of these functions, the data is automatically cached by default for subsequent re-renders of the same component.

To achieve the desired behavior, you can use useFetch or useAsyncData to fetch the test data initially. Once the data is fetched, subsequent clicks on the same test will not trigger another network request; instead, the cached data will be used for display.